# how and using which library can i use knn imputation for missing value analysis

Tags: python, missing-data, knn, imputation

I am trying to to impute the missing values using knn but i couldnt able to use the 
code: 
from fancyimpute import KNN
is there any other library for knn imputation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative library is `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
```

An example from [skleanr's documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer

X = [[1, 2, np.nan], [3, 4, 3], [np.nan, 6, 5], [8, 8, 7]]
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2)
imputer.fit_transform(X)
```

Output:

```
array([[1. , 2. , 4. ],
       [3. , 4. , 3. ],
       [5.5, 6. , 5. ],
       [8. , 8. , 7. ]])
```

Comment: First of all thankyou for the response!
actually i wanted to impute the missing values in the data with 22 variables ...and i wanted to impute in the same file itself but when i used the knnimputer my output comes in the form of array like this 
array([[ 55.,   0.,   2., ..., 999.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 40.,   1.,   1., ..., 999.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 42.,   9.,   1., ..., 999.,   0.,   0.],
       ...,
       [ 27.,   1.,   2., ..., 999.,   3.,   0.],
       [ 51.,  10.,   0., ..., 999.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 38.,   1.,   1., ..., 999.,   0.,   0.]])

Comment: If it's a dataframe, you can use the array to replace the value in the series (given they have the same length)